# UNIX config file issue

Tags: unix, replace, configuration-files, vi

An issue I'm having is trying to update values in the configuration file using VI.  So change the value in the lines according to a matched pattern.
For example, with a configuration file as below (continuing till infinity with no line numbers)....how would I append an # to all lines with string abc in them? i.e. line 1 and 3.

I'm trying :$s/abc/^/#/g with no luck.  I'd like to comment out both 1 and 3 basiscally.

Appreciate any thoughts on this.

```
1 abc xyz
2 def odc
3 abc nui
4 ghi rud
```

Comment: If the file "continues to infinity", then it's not a regular file.  So you want to use a stream editor like sed.  How are you able to load this stream into vi?

Comment: `:$s/abc/^/` searches for the string `abc` and replaces it with the string `^`, but the replacement is restricted to the last line. (The `$` before the `s` indicates that the operation should only occur on the last line.)

Comment: sorry, not 'till infinity' but quite a big file with no line numbers.

Comment: sorry again, I meant = :%s/abc/^/#/g

Comment: I'd like it to search the file for lines with 'abc' and place a comment (#) at the beginning of these lines (^).  In reality, there are only 4 lines in a big file with 'abc',

Answer (score 0):

In vim, you could do:

```
:g/abc/s/^/#/
```